# Erase content in Google Apps Script Document Service

Tags: google-apps-script

How to flush a document in Google Apps Script Document Service? Do I need to loop through all the kind of elements e.g. paragraph, image, table and remove them as a child? Is there an easier way to delete everything in the body of a document?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document#setText), the `Document.setText` should be able to clear the document content. I assume the following command should do it.

```
doc.setText('');
```

Comment: Nice solution ! works as expected ;-)  `function eraseContent(docId){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  doc.setText('');
}`

Answer (score 2):

In the current [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document) of google apps script as doc.setText method is not available this could be achieved by doc.getBody().clear()

Answer (score 0):

May i mention that the body.clear() method does not remove bookmarks, because they are associated with the document.

This worked for me:

```
scratchBody = scratchDoc.getBody();
scratchBody.clear();
bookmarks   = scratchDoc.getBookmarks();
while ( bookmarks.length ) { bookmarks.shift(); }
```

I didn't try this yet, but as with the bookmarks, there could be the HeaderSection, the FooterSection, and the FootnoteSections remaining in the document.