# Clear a document using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a form that generates a report every new answer in a specific document (to not create a new one on every new answer). I'm having some difficult to clear the old report to write a new one.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590434/erase-content-in-google-apps-script-document-service/11591462) question and it worked when I have only text but, although it says that removes images too, it dosen't.

Any idea to remove the images?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but if I add something after the image (in my case, a table), `doc.setText('')` clears all.